# If $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=10$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y+Z)=20$, what is the upper bound for $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y+Z)$?

Tags: variance

The lower bound can be zero, by having covariance matrix

$\Sigma= \begin{bmatrix} 20 & -20 & 0\\ -20 & 30 & -10 \\ 0 & -10 & 10\end{bmatrix}$

producing

$$[1,1,0]^T \Sigma [1,1,0]=10$$
$$[0,1,1]^T \Sigma [0,1,1]=20$$
$$[1,1,1]^T \Sigma [1,1,1]=0$$

That shows the lower bound for $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y+Z)$can be zero. Is the upper bound possibly infinite?

I tried numerically solving for the elements within the covariance matrix as possible unknowns and is 6 variable constrained optimization - but then realized the constructed matrices may not be positive semidefinite. Then switched to constructing matrix $S$, such that $\Sigma = S S^T$ and finding elements within $S$ which maximizing $[1,1,1]^T \Sigma [1,1,1]$ and obtained a weird looking numerical values of

$\Sigma= \begin{bmatrix} 6735.93 & -6676.96 & 6648.38\\ -6676.96 & 6628.&  -6603.29 \\ 6648.38 & -6603.29 & 6598.59\end{bmatrix}$

producing

$$[1,1,1]^T \Sigma [1,1,1]=6698.77$$

which led to me to believe it is actually infinite. (May be making the analysis harder than it actually is, and over-thinking it)

Comment: Use variables $U=X+Y,$ $V=Y+Z,$ and $Y.$  Now your question asks for bounds on the variance of $U+V-Y$ subject to conditions on the variances of $U$ and $V.$  If, for simplicity, you assume $Y$ is uncorrelated with $U$ or $V,$ what are the possible variances of $Y$?  What does that imply about the possible variances of $U+V-Y$?

Comment: And yeap, definitely was overthinking it. Unbounded. Thanks!